# What applications does the quantum gate [(i,1),(1,i)] have?

Tags: quantum-gate, matrix-representation

I've been working through the great introduction to quantum computing on [Quantum Country](https://quantum.country/qcvc). One exercise there is to find a possible quantum gate matrix that is not the $X,I$ or $H$ matrix.

I thought of $B = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}i & 1\\1 & i\end{bmatrix}$. However, I cannot find any article / paper mentioning this quantum gate.

From what I understood, all quantum gates must be $2\times2$, unitary matrices. I have even checked whether $B$ is indeed unitary, and [yes, it is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is%20(1%2Fsqrt(2))*%5B(i,1),(1,i)%5D%20unitary%3F).

Why does this gate $B$ not have any useful applications? Or is it just not a valid gate?

Comment: It's a fine question that deserves an answer longer than a comment, but not all quantum gates need to be $2\times 2$ - similarly, not all classical gates need to be two-input (think of an [AOI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AND-OR-Invert) - and/or/invert - gate).  The [Toffoli gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate) is $3\times 3$.  They do have to be reversible, as in unitary, however.

Comment: @MarkS As a point of note with respect to the Toffoli gate, that's a three-qubit operation, such that its unitary representation is a $2^3 \times 2^3$ operator.

Comment: I must say that it's a weird exercise. There are infinitely many possible single qubit quantum gates that are not $X$, $I$, or $H$. We don't even need to delve into two-qubit or three-qubit operations.

Comment: @ChrisGranade thanks!  Sorry for the blunder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not the right way to look at it. In quantum mechanics, time evolutions are [considered to be unitary](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/169936) and any unitary evolution can be written as a sequence of unitary operators $U_1, U_2, U_3,\ldots$ acting on a quantum state $|\Psi\rangle$. Any single-qubit [unitary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix#Elementary_constructions) is a $2\times 2$ matrix of the form:

$$U=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-e^{i\phi}b^*&e^{i\phi} a^*\end{pmatrix}, |a|^2+|b|^2=1.$$

In your case, $a=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}$, $b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\phi=\pi$. Now, $B$ isn't one of the "popular" quantum gates like the Pauli or the Hadamard, but that doesn't mean it can't be a valid evolution operator! The Hadamard and the Pauli are generally chosen because they have some neat properties; for instance, the Pauli matrices form a basis for all $2\times 2$ Hermitian matrices. For more, read the Wikipedia pages on [Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) and [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). Moreover, note that some gates can be easier to engineer than others; I had written [an answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1280) about this before. Also see: [Why do we use the standard gate set that we do?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1587/26).

So for drawing quantum circuits we generally try to choose a [universal gate set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Universal_quantum_gates) that's also relatively easy to physically implement. Now *any* unitary evolution can be replicated with an $\epsilon>0$ precision, with a sufficient number of elementary quantum gates which form a universal set. Niel de Beaudrap also wrote [a nice answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/4250) on this topic. Perhaps, as an exercise, you can try to write the $B$ gate in terms of the elementary quantum gates listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Universal_quantum_gates)?

If you notice carefully, $\sqrt{\operatorname{NOT}}=\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}B$. That is, $B$ differs from the $\sqrt{\operatorname{NOT}}$ (or $\sqrt{X}$) by a simple phase factor! Thus, $\sqrt{\operatorname{NOT}}$ and $B$ are essentially the same gate cf. [Norbert Schuch's answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/3889). For a physical implementation of $\sqrt{\operatorname{NOT}}$ check [Jones, Hansen & Mosca (1998)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1090780798916068).

I suggest playing around with it a bit on [Quirk](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:[[%22~cjl9%22]],%22gates%22:[%7B%22id%22:%22~cjl9%22,%22name%22:%22B%22,%22matrix%22:%22%7B%7B%E2%88%9A%C2%BDi,%E2%88%9A%C2%BD%7D,%7B%E2%88%9A%C2%BD,%E2%88%9A%C2%BDi%7D%7D%22%7D]%7D). The [Bloch sphere intuition](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2279/26) should help:

[image: Source:https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.67.094510]

You see, both $\sqrt{X}$ and $B$ rotate a qubit state around $\hat{x}$ by $90^{\mathrm{o}}$, albeit with different phase factors.

Comment: Another way to notice that $B = e^{i\phi} \sqrt X$ is by noticing that $B^2=iX$. Same thing, just a different way of writing it that I found easier to spot

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 you made a typo $B^2=iX$ not $iX^2$.

Comment: Whoops... I've fixed that now...